# My question is regarding the order of the words

Tags: word-order

I came across a sentence, which struck me a bit unusual. My question is regarding the order of the words. Why does "for me" go after "would be" in this case? Is it correct? "The best thing for me" sounds more natural for me.

Here's the sentence:

> The best thing would be for me to take Amy and go where no one will ever find us.

Comment: The best thing would be (for me (to take Amy and go where no one will ever find us)).

Comment: The two different orders have two different meanings.

Comment: Shouldn't your username be either *“Me**um** Mysteri**um”*** in the neuter singular or else *“Me**a** Mysteri**a***” in the neuter plural? That way the numbers and genders would both match. Are you trying to use a feminine *mea* because you think it would work like English and reflect the sex of the possessor rather than the gender of the thing possessed?  Merely compare John Sebastian Bach’s [*Magnificat anima mea*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IzGe3zOnts) with Tomás Luis de Victoria’s [*O magnum mysterium*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xPh-fXYAc4) to meditate upon these mysteries. :)

Comment: _For me_ precedes, and is the subject of, the conjoined infinitive clause _to take Amy and go where no one will ever find us_. That infinitive clause is the complement of _The best thing would be_, which comprises the beginning of the main clause. So the reason why _for me_ is where it is is that it isn't saying who springing into action is the best thing for -- rather, it's saying who should be springing into action. In other words, it's not part of the main clause; it's part of the subordinate clause and that's why it appears there.

Comment: @Peter Shor, yeah! Somehow I didn't think of it this way. Thank you!

Comment: @John Lawler, got it! Many thanks!

Comment: @tchrist, my nickname has nothing to do with grammatical right things :) I didn't have that aim. I just like the way it sounds. I focused exactly on the phonetic aspect.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> *For me* precedes, and is the subject of, the conjoined infinitive clause *to take Amy and go where no one will ever find us*. That infinitive clause is the complement of *The best thing would be*, which comprises the beginning of the main clause. So the reason why *for me* is where it is is that it isn't saying who springing into action is the best thing for -- rather, it's saying who should be springing into action. In other words, it's not part of the main clause; it's part of the subordinate clause and that's why it appears there.

Comment: I can only vote for the answer as 'useful', but it is also correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Both word orders are correct but mean different things. “The best thing would be” means what follows is the best thing for everyone. “The best thing for me would be” means the thing that follows is the best if I care only for my own interests and not for others.

“For me to take Amy” = “I take Amy”. If you moved “for me” to the front, this likely just becomes “to take Amy” because it is clear from context that it is me taking her.